# How to restrict the access of concurrent program(Oracle report) to few users only?

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I need to give Oracle XML report access to only some users and not responsibility specific.For eg only 3 users can run a particular concurrent program and no one else.

Please suggest all the possible ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge the only possible way to achieve that would be to check in the BEFOREREPORT module if the logged in user is one of the ones enlisted in your 'white list'